# Nginx configuration file with sf2, php-fpm and fastCGI

Tags: nginx, php, symfony

This is my config file, it's taken from the official symfony 2 website so it should work:

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    root /var/www/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

---

Entering `www.domain.com/` works as expected, but any other route throws 500 error (when the second/third location block is executed).

I tried:

```
www.domain.com/test/
www.domain.com/app.php/test/
www.domain.com/app_dev.php/test/ (can't access app.dev.php error)
www.domain.com/web/app.php/test/
```

None works.

I also don't get neigher nginx, nor application logs when I enter those addresses (`/` route creates logs as expected).

If it was code's fault, I would get some logs, wouldn't I?

What is wrong? I have no idea how could I track those errors, I can't create working configuration.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: I wrote it, nothing. `error.log` doesn't show anything new on this 500 error page refresh, project_error.log does not either.

Comment: How can I debug this?